# Why some stocks not traded today?

Tags: equities, market-data, historical-data, price

I try to download market daily data after US markets close.

I found that the stocks in the following list have no data today.

```
LBTYB
WLYB
CSTA
SAGA
FSRX
HVBC
CMCA
ELSE
WSO-B
...
```

I try to find the OHLC data on TradingView and Yahoo Finance, but they don't have today's data for the stocks on the above list.

I did not find any news or announcement about those stocks. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a common misconception that everything must trade every day / hour / minute when the market is open.

Quite simply, the price is in equilibrium - no new buyers willing to push the bid higher and no sellers wishing to push the ask lower.

There may be various reasons for this - there might be alternative classes of stock to trade (eg. LBTYA instead of LBTYB, WLY instead of WLYB etc.) or quite simply the stock just isn't very liquid (some of the SPACs you mentioned) or just has a low market cap (eg. HVBC is considered to be a Microcap).

If you seek liquidity you should instead consider stocks that are constituents of higher cap indices such as S&P 500, Russell 1000, etc.

Comment: Thanks!! I have further questions for that: (1) how to treat this situation to calculate technical indicators? (2) how to aggregate those data into weekly bars if there are only one trade day in the week?

Comment: Please create a new question for follow up questions after using the search.